# Why is my wireless speed slow?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-router

I have a dual-band router that supports gigabit wireless and up to 160MHz-wide channels in the 5GHz spectrum and 40MHz-wide channels in the 2.4GHz spectrum. I have gigabit internet, but when I connect to the 2.4GHz spectrum of my router using my laptop which has an [Intel 9560](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/99446/intel-wireless-ac-9560.html) Wi-Fi chip, I only get speeds of up to 100Mbps sitting next to the router.

Doesn't 802.11n support 300Mbps in 40MHz channel width? Connecting to the 5GHz band improves speeds significantly, 350Mbps down and 650Mbps up using 80MHz channel width. But my Wi-Fi card supports gigabit speeds! Why can't I get gigabit wireless speeds? I don't want to use 160MHz channels as that uses a huge chunk of the wireless spectrum.

P.S. Only one device was connected to my router while testing.

Comment: Did you try updating / reinstalling the wireless driver? I am not clear on your reason for avoiding 5 GHz.  I use this band and my wireless AC card whenever I can.

Comment: @John Yes, I did. I only use 5ghz, but why am I not getting at least near gigabit speeds using Wireless AC? Why I am only getting half of that? There is no 5ghz interference from nearby networks too.

Comment: **(1)** Have you set actual channels on your radios (should never be set to _auto_)? If in the US, 2.4GHz works best on channels 1, 6, and 11; whereas 5GHz works best on the highest channels possible, with 157 generally working the best for 80MHz, but to get over the 867Mbit/s max speed of the 80MHz bandwidth, you'd have to use 160MHz (recommended when both client and router support it).  If not in the US, google which channels work best in the country you're in; **(2)** Have you configured your WiFi card's settings using either the adapter's properties in Windows or Intel's PRO/Set software?

Comment: Try updating the Firmware on the Router. Then (a) try a different computer to test against and (b) try connecting directly to the ISP modem. The router may not be providing proper throughput. 100Mbits/sec seems too slow.

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, I am using the non-overlapping channels in the 2.4ghz range, and I think I'm happy with 80mhz as the max speed I get wired speeds of 850, so I'm good. My router doesn't support 160mhz sadly. :(

Comment: @John I am running the latest firmware on the router and I am using a cat5e cable to connect to my modem, and my router supports 1-gigabit throughput, using another laptop produces same problem. Mind you this issue is only in the 2.4ghz band, 5ghz band speeds are better 350mbps down/ 650mbps up. Maybe the issue is because of interference from nearby wifi devices, wifi analyzer shows around 20 Access points using 2.4Ghz. :(

Comment: @Sudo What matters is what channels those other 2.4GHz radios are using (1, 6, 11 are DFS channels). I'd remove the 160MHz mention in your question, as both the router and client must support it.  To build on John's comment, if your router is over 1yr old, you may want to consider flashing opensource firmware like [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/), as OEMs consider a router EoL [End of Life] after 1yr, 2yrs at most, at which point no further firmware updates will be released - this results in routers becoming security risks due to no longer receiving security patches for CVEs.

Comment: Have you tried using an ethernet cable to check if it receiving a gigabit in the first place? Wired speed of 850 are definitely less, assuming the loss in wired to wireless transmission it seems that you should try another router for an instance and make sure it is the router causing the problem. Also 2.4 ghz band definitely won’t be able to coup up with the 5 ghz band.

Comment: @Valay_17 I don't get exactly gigabit, more like 800 mbps up and down, by running a speed test in the router login page and I don't get any packet loss using an ethernet cable, I tried using another router but still get the same speeds, I do get gigabit at non-peak times using an ethernet cable. :) I guess what's limiting my wireless speed is interference.

Comment: @JW0914 sadly my router radios will get buggy if I use OpenWRT, i have seen the reviews of OpenWrt on my Netgear R8000P and it says that DFS channels are not supported, which is not good as there is already many aps which use the non-DFS channels in my area. :(

Comment: And thank you guys for so much help and suggestions!

Comment: @Sudo DFS non-support doesn't affect what channel width you can configure the radios with... a radio driver that doesn't implement DFS would simply not dynamically switch to a channel in one of the [DFS blocks](https://kb.netgear.com/000060378/Which-Dynamic-Frequency-Selection-channels-does-my-NETGEAR-router-support) if it detects RADAR interference.  This doesn't mean there may not be performance issues on OpenWrt, but depending on how old those reviews are and for what OpenWrt version (current version is 19.07.2), you may want to check out the [OpenWrt Forum](https://forum.openwrt.org).

Comment: @JW0914 Isn't that illegal.. like avoiding radar checks?

Comment: @JW0914 Oh... and my bad I actually have the Netgear R8000**P** which is a tri-band router and **NOT** supported by openwrt

Comment: @Sudo _Fact-checking would need to be performed_, but I doubt it, as radio drivers either support or do not support DFS and the opensource drivers for brcm* radios don't appear to [support](https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/dfs) it.  OEMs are required to abide by FCC regulations, but if they don't make the driver coding for DFS available to be implemented in an opensource driver, I doubt the onus falls on the consumer _(again, fact-checking needs to be performed)_.

Comment: @Sudo Ok so your router does work and also your 5 ghz band is working fine, but you think that your 2.4 ghz isn’t giving you enough speed right? A small note 2.4 ghz supports maximum of 600 mbps under ideal conditions so it seems that you are getting almost perfect speed from your router. If you want to make sure that interference is the cause, you could try building a small faraday cage(just in case you got some metal sheets lying around).

Comment: Also did you check that your wi-fi card only supports 802.11ac and not 802.11n ? In the question it mentions you only use 802.11n did you try using either a or c for once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You're already getting exactly what you should expect to get, given the hardware you're using. The marketing for your R8000P is very misleading and seems to have (successfully?) misled you into believing that you should be getting better performance. Your R8000P's capabilities are not a good match for what your Intel 9560 client chipset is capable of, and since the two devices can only communicate using speedup tricks they *both* support, it turns out that 100Mbps on 2.4GHz and 600Mbps on 5GHz is about all you can expect out of that particular mismatched hardware pairing.

**Long Answer:**

Your Intel 9560 only supports full gigabit speeds when using 160MHz-wide channels and 2 spatial streams. Since 160MHz-wide channels are only available with 802.11ac or better in 5GHz, that means it can only do it in 5GHz.

Your NETGEAR R8000P AP does **not** support 160MHz-wide channels. So your Intel 9560 will never be able to get full gigabit speeds with that AP.

**Here's the scoop on what your R8000P is really capable of:**

**2.4GHz radio: Claimed speed: 750Mbps. Realistic speed: 100Mbps.**

Your R8000P has a 2.4GHz radio chipset from Broadcom that uses Broadcom-proprietary tricks to claim a signaling rate of **750Mbps**. But your Intel client can't do those tricks, so that alone would bump you down to a standards-based signaling rate of **450Mbps**. But 450Mbps is based on 3 spatial streams (sometimes written "3SS", or "3x3:3" or a variant thereof) which your AP supports but your client doesn't. So with your Intel client, you'll only be able to do 2SS, which bumps you down to a **300Mbps** signaling rate. But even that 300Mbps signaling rate is based on using 40MHz-wide channels, which is problematic on 2.4GHz. 40MHz-wide channels hog too much of the band and don't leave enough room for Bluetooth, so there's a way for 2.4GHz Wi-Fi devices that also support Bluetooth to signal to the AP that they are "40MHz intolerant", which forces the AP and other clients of the AP to only use 20MHz-wide transmissions, in order to leave more room for Bluetooth. Your Intel 9560 is probably doing this, so that bumps you down to **144Mbps**. After that, we have typical Wi-Fi overhead of about 30%, which bumps you down to **100Mbps**. And that's under ideal signal strength and low noise/interference. If you don't have clear line of sight to your AP, or if you're farther than about 5m away, or if all the 2.4GHz channels are crowded with other users around you, you won't even get that.

**5GHz radios x2: Claimed speed: 1625Mbps each. Realistic speed: 600Mbps each.**

Your R8000P again uses Broadcom proprietary tricks to claim a signaling speed of **1625Mbps** for each of its two 5GHz radios. But again, your Intel client only supports the standards, so that would bump you down to **1300Mbps**. And again, your Intel client is only 2SS, so that bumps you down to **867Mbps**. And again, there is typical Wi-Fi overhead of about 30%, bringing you down to about **600Mbps** under ideal radio conditions. So if you're not close enough to the AP, or if the channel is busy from neighbor networks, you won't even get 600Mbps.

So, given the equipment you have, the fact that you're seeing around **100Mbps on 2.4GHz** and around **600Mbps on 5GHz**, that's actually right in line with what the standard data rate arithmetic suggests you should expect given the technical details of the Wi-Fi radios in your NETGEAR R8000P AP and Intel 9560 client.

If you want to get full gigabit speeds with your Intel 9560 client, you should replace your R8000P with an R7800. The R7800 supports 160MHz-wide channels. You **MUST** use 160MHz-wide channels to get full gigabit speeds with your Intel 9560 chipset. That's the only way that it supports gigabit speeds. If you cut the channel width in half to 80MHz, you cut your potential throughput in half. If you try to use old/slow/narrow/crowded 2.4GHz, you cut your potential throughput to a very small slice of your hardware's actual potential.

Answer (score -1):

> Doesn't 802.11n support 300Mbps in 40mhz channel width?

Probably a completely silly answer, but re-test with your laptop connected to mains power.

I've [heard of](https://twitter.com/Toble_Miner/status/1202913249311809536) some Intel Wi-Fi drivers and/or chips limiting themselves to 1 spatial stream when battery-powered... and 802.11n is only 150 Mbps per stream (at 40 MHz).

Comment: Sadly it didn't work! :(